# Finding the correspondence of data from one data set in the other

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, kdtree

I have [a catalogue of data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3HWMYm2lTkVZmFrQTZHQnRoWGs) and I want to use it in my **MCMC** code. What is crucial is the speed of implementation, in order to avoid slowing down my Markov chain monte carlo sampling. 
**The problem**:
In the catalogue, I have in the first and second column two parameters called `ra` and `dec` which are *sky coordinates*:

```
data=np.loadtxt('Final.Cluster.Shear.NegligibleShotNoise.Redshift.cat')
ra=data[:,0]
dec=data[:,1]
```

then in the seven and eight columns `X` and `Y` positions, i.e. the grid coordinates, they are points in a grid space

```
Xpos=data[:,6]
Ypos=data[:,7]
```

In the function that I have written and it is needed to be called like a million time,
I will give one `Xcenter` and `Ycenter` positions (for example Xcenter=200.6, Ycenter=310.9) as inputs to the function and I want to find the correspondence points in the `ra` and `dec` columns. However it might happen that the inputs do not have any real correspondence in the `ra` and `dec`. So I want to do an interpolation in case there is no similar entries for `X` and `Y` and `ra` and `dec` data in the catalogue and obtain the interpolated coordinates based on real `ra` and `dec` entries in the catalogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case where the `scipy.spatial.cKDTree()` class can be used to query all the points at once:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

k = cKDTree(data[:, 6:8]) # creating the KDtree using the Xpos and Ypos

xyCenters = np.array([[200.6, 310.9],
                      [300, 300],
                      [400, 400]])
print(k.query(xyCenters))
# (array([ 1.59740195,  1.56033234,  0.56352196]),
#  array([ 2662, 22789,  5932]))
```

where `[ 2662, 22789,  5932]` are the indices corresponding to the three closest points given in `xyCenters`. You can use these indices to get your `ra` and `dec` values very efficiently using `np.take()`:

```
dists, indices = k.query(xyCenters)
myra = np.take(ra, indices)
mydec = np.take(dec, indices)
```