# Computing nearest neighbor point in 2D dimensions but only from previous times

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a large number of points in a 2D x-y plane, as well as time values associated with these points. I could organize this into a 2D array of size N x 3 (where N=# of points and 3 is the x,y,t pair).

As I go through the values sequentially in time, I'll occasionally need to compute the nearest neighbor (in x-y space) to my current point, but ONLY the nearest neighbor that's available from *previous* times. The reason I need to do this is to re-calibrate a different piece of information (let's call this Z). The idea is that the closest value of Z in x-y space from previous times won't have the offset that I'm re-calibrating for, whereas future times may need to be recalibrated themselves.

What would be an efficient approach to computing the nearest neighbor point, but only taken from previous times? I'm hoping to use Numpy, Scipy, and other python packages to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Perhaps [using cKDTree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551131/832621) is a good option for your case...

Comment: @SaulloCastro, thanks! I hadn't heard of cKDTree before. I'll look into it.