# Compute numpy array pairwise Euclidean distance except with self

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, euclidean-distance

edit: this question is not specifically about calculating distances, rather the most efficient way to loop through a numpy array, specifying that for index i all comparisons should be made with the rest of the array, as long as the second index is not i.

I have a numpy array with columns (X, Y, ID) and want to compare each element to each other element, but not itself. So, for each X, Y coordinate, I want to calculate the distance to each other X, Y coordinate, but not itself (where distance = 0).

Here is what I have - there must be a more "numpy" way to write this.

```
import math, arcpy
# Point feature class
fc = "MY_FEATURE_CLASS"
# Load points to numpy array: (X, Y, ID)
npArray = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(fc,["SHAPE@X","SHAPE@Y","OID@"])
for row in npArray:
    for row2 in npArray:
        if row[2] != row2[2]:
            # Pythagoras's theorem
            distance = math.sqrt(math.pow((row[0]-row2[0]),2)+math.pow((row[1]-row2[1]),2))
```

Obviously, I'm a numpy newbie. I will not be surprised to find this a duplicate, but I don't have the numpy vocabulary to search out the answer. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You may want to look at [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computing Euclidean distance for numpy in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687321/computing-euclidean-distance-for-numpy-in-python)

Comment: Note that in many geometries d(x, y) = 0 iff x = y, so you may want to skip that check, and deal with the zeros later on. Disregard this comment if you're dealing computing distance under a non-injective mapping - I just noticed you've discussing "features" in your code, which suggests this may be the case.

Comment: @PatrickMcLaren That may be. The main thrust behind the question is to find the nearest other geometry to a given geometry. If I leave in the zeros, then I'm looking for the second-nearest geometry to each geometry, which seems more complicated.

Comment: Well, if you are willing to use scipy, then the comment by @user2357112 should do the trick. If not, you could use a list comprehension, say `distances = [dist(x, y) for x in npArray for y in npArray if x != y]`, where `dist` is some metric.

Comment: In terms of math you could build a 3d tensor with sizes NxNx2 from two matrices of sized Nx2, by so-called `broadcasting` Nx2 matrix up to NxNx2 tensor and getting it's transposed version and subtracting them and then computing L2-norm over third axis. Than, I guess, you'd have exactly matrix of pair-wise distances.

Comment: @user2312518 I've been [using cKDTree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551131/832621) that comes in SciPy to do this kind of task very efficiently, it seems much faster than calculating all the distances

Answer (score 0):

Using SciPy's [**pdist**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), you could write something like

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

distances = squareform(pdist(npArray, lambda a,b: np.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)))
```

`pdist` will compute the pair-wise distances using the custom metric that ignores the 3rd coordinate (which is your ID in this case). `squareform` turns this into a more readable matrix such that `distances[0,1]` gives the distance between the 0th and 1st rows.

Answer (score 0):

Each row of `X` is a 3 dimensional data instance or point.
The output `pairwisedist[i, j]` is distance of `X[i, :]` and `X[j, :]`

```
X = np.array([[6,1,7],[10,9,4],[13,9,3],[10,8,15],[14,4,1]])
a = np.sum(X*X,1)
b = np.repeat( a[:,np.newaxis],5,axis=1)
pairwisedist = b + b.T -2* X.dot(X.T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out that custom written sqrt of sum of squares are prone to overflow and underflow. Bultin math.hypot, np.hypot are way safer for no compromise on performance

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

distances = squareform(pdist(npArray, lambda a,b: math.hypot(*(a-b))
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233365/7035448)