# More efficient way to get nearest center

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

My data object is an instance of:

```py
class data_instance:
    def __init__(self, data, tlabel):
        self.data = data # 1xd numpy array
        self.true_label = tlabel # integer {1,-1}
```

So far in code, I have a list called `data_history` full with `data_istance` and a set of `centers` (numpy array with shape (k,d)).

For a given data_instance `new_data`, I want:

- 1/ Get the nearest center to `new_data` from `centers` (by euclidean distance) let it be called `Nearest_center`.
- 2/ Iterate trough `data_history` and:

  - 2.1/ select elements where the nearest center is `Nearest_center` (result of 1/) into list called `neighbors`.
  - 2.2/ Get labels of object in `neighbors`.

Bellow is my code which work but it steel slow and I am looking for something more efficient.

**My Code**

For 1/

```py
def getNearestCenter(data,centers):

    if centers.shape != (1,2):
        dist_ = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(data-centers,2),axis=1)) # This compute distance between data and all centers

        center = centers[np.argmin(dist_)] # this return center which have the minimum distance from data

    else:
        center=centers[0]
    return center
```

For 2/ (To optimize)

```py
def getLabel(dataPoint, C, history):

    labels = []
    cluster = getNearestCenter(dataPoint.data,C)
    for x in history:
        if  np.all(getNearestCenter(x.data,C) == cluster):
            labels.append(x.true_label)
    return labels
```

Comment: One simple thing to do is instead of calculating Euclidean distance between `np.array([data]*len(centers))` and `centers`, just use the absolute value: `dist_ = np.abs(np.array([data]*len(centers)) - centers`. The minimum of both vectors is going to be the same. It probably won't be a significant portion of your runtime, but every little bit helps.

Comment: Are you doing `np.array([data]*len(centers))` just to replicate the 1 by d vector into a k by d array? You shouldn't have to do this, Numpy has [smart array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), so you should be able to do `data - centers` or perhaps `np.array(data) - centers`.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Thank you for comments dude, but I think that the main problem is with the `getLabel(dataPoint, C, history)` method

Comment: Why do you say that? To my eyes, `getLabel` is just a wrapper that calls `getNearestCenter` a bunch of times. The only way to make `getLabel` fast, with fixed `getNearestCenter`, would be to somehow make `np.all` or `list.append` faster… actually, you could try replacing the for loop and `append`, depending on how many elements `history` has, with a list comprehension/`map`. A profiler will tell you if appending to a list is the bottleneck, or `np.all` (unlikely), or as I suspect, something in `getNearestCenter`.

Comment: You are right ` getLabel` iterate through `history` list, the perfect solution is to avoid that loop.

Comment: @farhawa I'd go for `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` to find the nearest centers and get the indices to the closest entries, [check this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551131/832621)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use the optimized `cdist` from `scipy.spatial` which is more efficient than calculating it with numpy,

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dist = cdist(data, C, metric='euclidean')
dist_idx = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)
```

An even more elegant solution is to use `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` (as pointed out by @Saullo Castro in comments), which could be faster for a large dataset,

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

tr = cKDTree(C)
dist, dist_idx = tr.query(data, k=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```py
dist_ = np.argmin(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(data[:, None]-C,2),axis=2)),axis=1)
```

This should return the index of the nearest center in `centers` from each data point of `data`.